# android Intent received to onCreate multiple times

Tags: android

hi
I have added an app to the Gallery share menu. 
Selecting and sharing one image works fine and this code:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {
```

in my onCreate is executed.

The problem is when i press back(destroy) and open the app again
The same Intent is received in the onCreate.

I use the :

```
 android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

and the

```
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
```

The onNewIntent is not firing.
I suspect i must clear out the Intent somehow.
and been trying to find and answer but im stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution so i answer my question for anyones delight

Added this to manifest:

```
        <activity android:name=".ServicesDemo"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

Added this to my ServicesDemo:

```
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "onConfigurationChanged",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Orientation changes of the phone will trigger this method instead of onCreate

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your launchmode. It should be standard so each time it will initiate a new instance of activity.

As you are using a singleton so if you get back to your current activity again, it will not relaunched.

See this link for ref how launchmode works: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Yes that was strange that is firing again with the singeltop. will remove the singeltop and work from there. im suspecting im doing something more wrong. thanks for your reply

Comment: if u find my ans right pls make my ans right by clicking right side of my ans. so people will get benefit of it

Comment: I removed the singeltop and still the same. The thing is when i rotate my phone everything starts again. 
The "Intent intent = getIntent();" in the onCreate must be reset somehow because it still contain the first Intent and relaunch myasynctask

Comment: another phenomenon is if i press and holde HOME and select Gallery the Gallery is not put to front. Its like my activity has looked the gallery